# How to sum json object in Java 8

Tags: json, api, java-8

```
JSON: {productDetails=[{amount=20000.0, rValue=10000.00}, {amount=80000.0, rValue=6000.00} {amount=70000.0, rValue=0}]
```

I have to get the totalValue based on rValue and amount.

if rValue != 0 then sum only rValues thats is 10000+6000 = 16000 Else, get the amount = 70000

and then totalValue = rvalues + amount (16000+70000)

Please, can anyone suggest how can I in Java8.

```
List<Map> products= (List)products.get("productDetails");


    
    for (Map<String, Object> scheme : products) {
        log.info("scheme " + scheme.toString());
        BigDecimal rValue = Optional.ofNullable(scheme.get("rValue "))
            .map(Object::toString)
            .map(BigDecimal::new)
            .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        
        BigDecimal amount = Optional.ofNullable(scheme.get("amount"))
            .map(Object::toString)
            .map(BigDecimal::new)
            .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);


        log.debug("rValue : " + rValue );
        log.debug("amount: " + amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
BigDecimal reduced = products.stream().map(x -> {
            if (x.getrValue() != BigDecimal.ZERO)
                return x.getrValue();
            else return x.getAmount();
        }).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Complete example:

```
public class Ex1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
             new Product(new BigDecimal(20000), new BigDecimal(10000)),
             new Product(new BigDecimal(80000), new BigDecimal(6000)),
             new Product(new BigDecimal(70000), BigDecimal.ZERO)
        ));

        BigDecimal reduced = products.stream().map(x -> {
            if (x.getrValue() != BigDecimal.ZERO)
                return x.getrValue();
            else return x.getAmount();
        }).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

        System.out.println(reduced);

    }
}

class Product {
    BigDecimal amount;
    BigDecimal rValue;

    public Product(BigDecimal amount, BigDecimal rValue) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.rValue = rValue;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public BigDecimal getrValue() {
        return rValue;
    }

    public void setrValue(BigDecimal rValue) {
        this.rValue = rValue;
    }
}
```

and the result is: `86000`

Answer (score 0):

Create POJO object of

```
long amount, rValue
```

Turn your JSON to a list of these objects (using Gson / Jackson).

Stream the list and apply your business logic.